# How to make exactly Acceptance Criteria and Acceptance Testing in Spring MVC project?

Tags: scrum, user-acceptance-testing, scrumboard

How would you go about introducing acceptance tests into a team using the Spring MVC framework? What tools are available for this purpose?How would I make Acceptance criteria as a QA?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Acceptance Test Automation Framework available.
They allow you to easily define your Acceptance Tests (which is unambiguous and Verifiable).

They can be easily/automatically triggered to run all your defined Acceptance Tests.

These easy to implement framworks also support you to pursue Acceptance Test Driven Development (ATDD); thus checking on QA.

If acceptance tests are very well defined and exhaustive they can easily be used to check regressions with very little effort.

Few of such Acceptance Test Automation Framework are as follows :

1. [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/)
2. [Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/)
3. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) can also be used for acceptance test.
4. [StoryTeller](http://storyteller.tigris.org/)

There are many others which lets you achieve the goal. :)